# Dropdown List in an echo format (PHP)

Tags: php

I would like to place a dropdown list inside an echo as i am using it to update data. Here are the codes for php

```
        echo "Staff Name: " . "<input type = 'text' style = 'width: 200px' name ='name' value = '$staff_name' required>";
```

For HTML, i know that i need to do it this way, but i do not know how to apply to php(echo)

```
<select name="sbranch_no">
<option value="Intelligence">Intelligence</option>
<option value="Investigation">Investigation</option>
<option value="Manpower">Manpower</option>
<option value="Operations">Operations</option>
<option value="Police National Service">Police National Service</option>
<option value="Planning and Organization Development">Planning and Organization Development</option>
<option value="Service Quality">Service Quality</option>
<option value="Support and Technical">Support and Technical</option>
<option value="Training">Training</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you mean?

```
<?php
    echo '<select name="sbranch_no">
    <option value="Intelligence">Intelligence</option>
    <option value="Investigation">Investigation</option>
    <option value="Manpower">Manpower</option>
    <option value="Operations">Operations</option>
    <option value="Police National Service">Police National Service</option>
    <option value="Planning and Organization Development">Planning and Organization Development</option>
    <option value="Service Quality">Service Quality</option>
    <option value="Support and Technical">Support and Technical</option>
    <option value="Training">Training</option>
    </select>';

?>
```

Or perhaps

```
<?php
    $menu='<select name="sbranch_no">
        <option value="Intelligence">Intelligence</option>
        <option value="Investigation">Investigation</option>
        <option value="Manpower">Manpower</option>
        <option value="Operations">Operations</option>
        <option value="Police National Service">Police National Service</option>
        <option value="Planning and Organization Development">Planning and Organization Development</option>
        <option value="Service Quality">Service Quality</option>
        <option value="Support and Technical">Support and Technical</option>
        <option value="Training">Training</option>
        </select>';

    echo "some stuff... $menu ...more stuff";
?>
```